# How can i save hector slam online map *.tiff?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-groovy, hector, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i save hector slam map online running on rviz in a *.tiff file.?
i run bellow command but don't worked, why?

> ## rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126101/how-can-i-save-hector-slam-online-map-*.tiff?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [hector_geotiff](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_geotiff) package provides a node for saving RoboCup Rescue compliant GeoTiff files. This is separate package from [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) to facilitate separation and re-use. It could for example also be used together with gmapping (or any other source of grid maps). See also [this paper](http://www.gkmm.tu-darmstadt.de/publications/files/kohlbrecher2013opensource.pdf) for a high level overview and the [geotiff_mapper.launch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/master/hector_geotiff/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch) launch file for an example launch setup. This is also used in the hector_mapping [tutorial.launch](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/master/hector_slam_launch/launch/tutorial.launch).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1